# GestureDetector and ToolTip are not working together

Tags: flutter

I want to copy data to clipboard on taping on the text and also showing a ToolTip to user that data successfully copied.

But using `ToolTip` and tappable widget like `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` are not working together and only one of tap methods get called.
In this case, only toolTip is shown and data does not get copied to clipboard:

```
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  print('on Tap');//doesn't get tapped! So Items is not copied but tooltip is shown
                  await Clipboard.setData(
                    ClipboardData(
                      text: content,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Tooltip(
                  message: 'Copied!',
                  triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
                  child: Text('Copy Me'),
                ),
              )
```

And in this case, toolTip is not shown, but data gets copied to clipboard.

```
Tooltip(
                    message: 'Copied',
                    triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () async {
                        print('Pressed '); //in this case Press in printed, but toolTip is not showing
                        await Clipboard.setData(
                          ClipboardData(
                            text: content,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text('Copy Me'),
                    ),
                  ),
```

How can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Have you considered showing a snackbar when you have copied the text?  Check out https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars

Comment: @John I want to show a `tooltip`, not a `snackbar`.

Comment: According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html tooltips are meant to display text when something is long pressed.  I don't think they were meant for what you are wanting to use them for.  If you are wanting your "copied" message to show up on top of the item you are copying, consider using a Stack to  display the message on top of the widget.  And then use a variable in a StatefulWidget to control when your copied message is displayed.

Comment: Yes you are right but ToolTip also has tap trigger mode so It can be used on tap actions.

Comment: Your original question mentioned wanting to display something when the text was successfully copied.  Using a tooltip is just going to display something when the triggerAction has happened.  You'll still be displaying a "copied" message even if some error were to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I get what exactly you mean, but give it a try to this:

```dart
class CopyableTextWithTooltip extends StatelessWidget {
  CopyableTextWithTooltip({required this.content});

  final String content;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: content));

          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Copied!')));

          print('${(await Clipboard.getData('text/plain'))?.text}');
        },
        child: const Tooltip(message: 'Copy Me', child: Text('Copy Me')),
      );
}
```

or

```dart
class CopyableTextWithTooltip extends StatelessWidget {
  CopyableTextWithTooltip({required this.content});

  final String content;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Tooltip(
        message: 'Copy Me',
        child: const Text('Copy Me'),
        triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
        onTriggered: () async {
          await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: content));

          print('${(await Clipboard.getData('text/plain'))?.text}');
        },
      );
}
```

Comment: The second solution is working. Thanks @Hamed